# Ajax button in Cgridview doesn't work

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have CGriview with ajax button,but when i click on the button, the page refreshed and doesnt send ajax parameter to my action,my code is like this:

```
enter code here
array(
                        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                        'template'=>'{reset}',
                        'buttons'=>array(
                            'reset'=>array(
                                'label'=>'reset',
                         'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("place/viewHallModal/",array("row"=>"1"))',
                                'options'=>array(
                                    'class' => 'btn',
                                        'ajax'=>array(
                                            'type'=>'post',
                                            'url'=>'js:$(this).attr("href")',
                                            'update'=>'#section-update',
                                            'success' =>'js:function(data) {alert("suc");}'
                                        )), 
                             ),
                        ),

                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't 50+ reputation for commenting, so I can help you only with **answering to the question**.

In `jQuery` you can write this ajax function like this

```
...
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'your_url_will_goes_here',
   cache: false, // or true
   data: {
      'your_data': $variable,
      'your_data1': $variable1,
   },
   success: function(data){
      alert("success !");
});
....
```

but I couldn't see your `data` ajax function. 
So which `data` you want to pass to your action?

Answer (score 0):

In documentation

```
    'buttonID' => array
(
    'label'=>'...',     //Text label of the button.
    'url'=>'...',       //A PHP expression for generating the URL of the button.
    'imageUrl'=>'...',  //Image URL of the button.
    'options'=>array(), //HTML options for the button tag.
    'click'=>'...',     //A JS function to be invoked when the button is clicked.
    'visible'=>'...',   //A PHP expression for determining whether the button is visible.
)
```

Your button will be:

```
'reset'=>array(
            'label'=>'reset',
            'url'=>'#',
            'click'=>'js:function(){
               // here write your function
            }'
        ),
```

Comment: i change my code like this but it dosent work!!the page refresh after click on the button

Comment: may be don't know about events on click. try :
js:function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
//and now write all what you need
}

Answer (score 0):

```
I change my code like this,but dosent work yet and the page wes refreshed!!
....
array(
                        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                        'template'=>'{reset}',
                        'buttons'=>array(
                            'reset'=>array(
                                'label'=>'reset',
'url'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("place/viewHallModal/")',
                                'click'=>'js:function(){
                                        alert("click");
                                        $.ajax({
                                           type: "post",
                                           url: "js:$(this).attr("+"href"+")",
                                           cache: false, // or true
                                           data: {
                                              "your_data": "a",
                                              "your_data1": "b",
                                           },
                                           success: function(data){
                                              alert("success !");
                                            }
                                        });
                                }',
....

my function in the click event was run and show me the alert but it replace above url in the href of tag <a href=""></a> and when i click on the button go to that address!!
```

Comment: i remove the url and enter the url of the ajax manualy and it work.Thanksssss.